Determining when the operator $f \mapsto if'$ is self adjoint with a specific domain.
Considering the Hilbert space for $L^2([0, 1])$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we can define $T_z$ as the closure of $f \mapsto if'$ on the domain $\{f \in C^1([0, 1]): f(1) = zf(0)\}$. I think this domain is densely defined since $C_c^\infty(0, 1)$ is a subset of this domain and is dense in $L^2([0, 1])$.
I am trying to know $T_z$ is self adjoint for specific $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I was thinking of trying values of $z$ with $|z| = 1$ and was trying to understand the spectrum of $T_z$ better. Sorry I would write more but really am lost.
Note: this is a problem in the textbook I am reading by Hörmander.

You mean $C^2$?

@MartinBrandenburg Due to the $i$, it's probably instead a typo on $f'$ being replaced by $f''$ incorrectly?

@MartinBrandenburg In the textbook it says $C^1([0, 1])$ and I changed $C_c(0, 1)$ to $C_c^\infty(0, 1)$. I also changed to $f'$ my bad

This is an example of an operator whose adjoint should be fortunately easily computable. Hint: before checking self-adjointness, have you checked symmetry?

@BrunoB I am not entirely sure I might have made a mistake but I think it is symmetric when $|z| = 1$. I am using my domain properties.

Try to find $T_z^.$ Then you will see when $T_z=T_z^.$

@RyszardSzwarc I just noticed but the answer should be "never" because the functions are $C^1$ instead of $H^1$...

I used integration by parts but I got $\langle T_zf, g \rangle = if(x)\overline{g(x)} |_0^1 + \langle f, T_z g \rangle$ @BrunoB

@BrunoB You are right, the domain is not large enough. But we may ask about essential selfadjointness.

Your operator is not closed so it can't be the adjoint of any operator, let alone its own adjoint. You'll have to modify the domains. Otherwise follow @RyszardSzwarc's idea.

My apologies again I jsut reread the textbook question and it says closure of $f \mapsto if'$

Your answer is correct concerning symmetry $|z|=1.$ Now you have to deal with domains of the closure and that  of the adjoint.

Let $|z|=1.$ Assume $g\in D(T^*).$  Then there is $h$ such that
$$\langle Tf,g\rangle=\langle f,h\rangle,\quad f\in D(T)$$
Let $H(x)=\int\limits_0^xh(t)\,dt+c,$ where $c$ is chosen so that $H(1)=zH(0).$ We get
$$\int\limits_0^1 f'(x)\overline{[-ig(x)]}\,dx =\int\limits_0^1f(x)\overline{h(x)}\,dx \\
=f(1)\overline{H(1)}-f(0)\overline{H(0)}-\int\limits_0^1f'(x)\overline{H}(x)\,dx=-\int\limits_0^1f'(x)\overline{H}(x)\,dx$$
Therefore $H(x)=ig(x)$ and $T^*g=h=ig'.$ Moreover  $D(T^*)$ consists of all functions such that $g'\in L^2$ and $g(1)=zg(0).$
In order to prove that $\overline{T}=T^*$ it suffices to show that the defect indices are $0,$ i.e. $\ker(T^*-\lambda I)=\{0\}$ for every $\lambda\notin \mathbb{R}.$ To this end assume $T^*g=\lambda g.$ Then $ig'=\lambda g.$ Thus $g$ is a $C^\infty$ function. The solutions are  $g(x)=ce^{-i\lambda x}.$ Moreover $g(0)=c$ while $g(1)=ce^{-i\lambda}.$ As $\lambda$ is not real we get $|g(1)|\neq |g(0)|$ unless $c=0.$

Hey, this is making sense. I am a bit confused why we are allowed to conclude that $H(x) = ig(x)$, so we have essentally shown that $\langle f', ig \rangle = \langle f', H \rangle$. Also would I use stone wes to show that my original domain is dense in $L^2$?

We have $\langle f',ig-H\rangle =0.$ The set of $f',$ where $f\in C^1$ and $f(1)=zf(0),$ is equal $C[0,1].$ As $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2$ we get $ig-H=0.$ Concerning $D(T)$ you mentioned in your post that  C^\infty_c(0,1)$ dens in $L^2(0,1).$ It ispossible to give a direct proof of that without referring to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

I think from your explanation I understand the most of how this question works. However I am still a little confused why the set of $f' \in C^1$ with $f(1) = zf(0)$ is equal to $C[0, 1]$. Obviously it is a subset.

The antiderivative is not determined uniquely. You can always choose the antiderivative of $f'$ so that the additional condition on the endpoints is satisfied.
